# How can I make vim use html and markdown syntax highlighting on the same file?

Tags: html, vim, syntax, markdown, remarks

I use [remark](http://remarkjs.com/) to make html slides from markdown code in vim.

Remark requires to use an [html template](https://github.com/gnab/remark/blob/develop/boilerplate-remote.html) containing both html and markdown code in it.

How can I make vim use both html and markdown syntax highlighting on the same html file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default Markdown syntax plugin (by Tim Pope) that ships with Vim already includes HTML syntax. From `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim`:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language:     Markdown
" Maintainer:   Tim Pope <vimNOSPAM@tpope.org>
" Filenames:    *.markdown
" Last Change:  2013 May 30

[7 lines deleted]

runtime! syntax/html.vim
unlet! b:current_syntax
```

Comment: Tim Pope's markdown also supports [fenced code blocks](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2x5yav/markdown_with_fenced_code_blocks_is_great/). Sadly this is not documented.